Reading Boxplots in Multiple Logistic Regression
Assuming a paradigm of logistic regression, I'm having some trouble understanding what particular model is suggested by some parallel boxplots. For example, here:

I'm told the model suggested is:
$$\text{log(odds)} = \beta 0 + \beta 1(\text{AHigh}) + \beta 2(\text{AHigh} \times X)$$
In other words, just the categorical variable ($\text{A=High/Low}$) and the interaction term, not the continuous variable ($X$), but I'm not sure why. The average $X$ value is clearly higher for the $Y=1$ groups than the $Y=0$ group, so shouldn't it be significant? What suggests the categorical variable is significant? How am I supposed to tell the interaction term is significant? There's a second plot that I'm equally as confused about - what model is suggested here?


For the first plot, it seems there is at least a visually clear positive interaction as $A = \text{High}$. While it seems there are more $Y=1$ responses on average across both $A$ groupings, the median/IQR clearly increases when $A = \text{High}$. For the second plot, there is an interaction which shows that for $A = \text{High}$, the average $Y=0$ response increases a lot, while it remains fairly the same for $Y=1$.
Whether either is statistically significant isn't clear, as these do not look like estimated marginal means (EMMs). EMMs are, loosely, the means of model predictions after controlling for all factor combinations. If your effects were statistically significant, the confidence interval lines shouldn't overlap if they are indeed statistically significant.
On the contrary, these seem to at surface value look like ordinary boxplots, which have not accounted for the model predictions (where the raw means of $X$ may be biased given covariance structures, confounds, etc. are not accounted for). There appears to be a clear descriptive difference between the groups from the boxplots, but its not entirely certain that they are statistically significant here.

First, I am leery of a model like the one someone suggested to you. While there are exceptions, it rarely makes sense to have an interaction term without both main effects (here, X and A). You can see what a model without both main effects is saying by plugging in various values of X and A and looking at the predicted values.
Second, I am also leery of getting models from box plots. This sounds a lot like HARKing (hypothesizing after the results are known) and that is frowned upon.  See this Wikipedia article or Kerr (1998) HARKing: Hypoothesizing after the Results are Known. Personality and Social Psychology Review 2, 196-217, or this thread on the "Texas Sharpshooter Fallacy" which is related.
You have to separate exploratory data analysis from hypothesis testing. In the latter, your hypotheses should come from theory, or prior results (on a different data set).

I hadn't considered the more post-hoc way that they derived their model until reading your answer. Critical point that OP should consider.
